# lshw -C network shows Ethernet "network unclaimed"

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

```
   *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 03
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
```

Using "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM".
Ubuntu : 18.04
Kernel : 5.4.0-128-generic

## modprobe igc; dmesg

> igc 0000:01:00.0: no suspend buffer for PTM
> igc: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -2

Comment: What OS are you using?  You mention Ubuntu 18.04 then a non-Ubuntu kernel; is your system Ubuntu based and not Ubuntu as your details contradict.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with 5.4.0-128-generic kernel. Somewhere I saw the solution that updating a kernel may resolve the issue but still Ethernet is not working after updating kernel so reverted back to original ubuntu kernel 5.4.0-128-generic.

Comment: I suggest you try a live session of Ubuntu 22.04 and see if the later kernel; i.e. 5.15, resolves the issue.

Comment: Keep min mind Ubuntu 18.04 has only 5 months of support left. There's really no point in troubleshooting it if the current release already supports it.

Comment: @sandip I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin Please start your own new question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Ubuntu 18.04` is incompatible with newer hardware. (Apparently network drivers are built directly into the kernel, and so Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have the newest Intel drivers.)

Upgrading from `Ubuntu 18.04` to `Ubuntu 22.04` `(Using a USB tethered smartphone to provide internet)` solved the issue.

Comment: As a side note, as ChanganAuto said, `Ubuntu 18` reached end-of-life on May 2023, so nobody should be using it anyways.